# Cut or Awk to save lines on array in bash

Tags: bash, awk, array, cut

I have a scenario that I have to put lines of a file .txt inside an array, example of file content;

```
 type of host
 |
 |   first host
 |   |
 |   | second host
 |   | |     
 |   | |     same ip address 
 |   | |     |
HOST_A_B=192.168.0.1
```

I have to put this on array in bash

```
    #echo $Array[0]
    HOST_A=192.168.0.1
    #echo $Array[1]
    HOST_B=192.168.0.1
```

and sometimes the lines don't have a second HOST like

```
HOST_A_B=192.168.0.1
HOST_C=192.168.0.2
HOST_DEF_G=192.168.0.3
```

and the echo command output should looks like,

```
    #echo $Array[1]
    HOST_A=192.168.0.1
    #echo $Array[2]
    HOST_B=192.168.0.1
    #echo $Array[3]
    HOST_C=192.168.0.2
    #echo $Array[4]
    HOST_DEF=192.168.0.3
    #echo $Array[5]
    HOST_G=192.168.0.3
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are those lines with `> Array pos` the actual, literal output format you want?  or are they some kind of abstract description of what you want? If the latter, then please add a sample of the actual output format.  Also add a small but representative sample of your actual input file.

Comment: oh man, sorry, I have no idea what i wrote before.

Answer (score 5):

Could be something like:

```bash
readarray -t array < <(
  awk '
    match($0, /^HOST_[^=]+=/) {
      host = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH - 1)
      ip = substr($0, RLENGTH)
      n = split(host, hosts, "_")
      for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) print "HOST_"hosts[i] ip
    }' < your-file
)
```

On your sample, that gives:

```bash
$ typeset -p array
declare -a array=(
  [0]="HOST_A=192.168.0.1"
  [1]="HOST_B=192.168.0.1"
  [2]="HOST_C=192.168.0.2"
  [3]="HOST_DEF=192.168.0.3"
  [4]="HOST_G=192.168.0.3"
)
```